# Using signalr with one to one including offline modus

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am trying to implement a chat, from one client to another client. While searching I came across the interesting SignalR library, used for server push actions.

Say a client sends another client a message, but that client is offline at the moment. When he comes back online he should see a notification that he has received a message while he was offline.
Does SignalR store its conversations somewhere? How can I store conversations in my database? How can I make the client see a notification when he has received an offline message?

Can anyone provide me with such a tutorial? I only found tutorials with online-online chat.

Kind regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SignalR does not provide offline messaging by itself.

You will have to store the offline messages in a database or somewhere and provide the logic to notify the users for the pending messages.

A naïve implementation:

```
public class ClientHub : Hub
{
    public SendMessage(string message, string targetUserName)
    {
        var userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        if (HubHelper.IsConnected(targetUserName))
        {
            Clients.User(targetUserName).sendMessage(message);
        }
        else
        {
            DataAccess.InsertPendingMessage(userName, targetUserName, message);
        }
    }

    public SendPendingMessages()
    {
            // Get pending messages for user and send it
            var meesages = DataAccess.GetPendingMessages(userName);
            Clients.User(userName).processPendingMessages(messages);    
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var connected = base.OnConnected();
        var userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
        {
            HubHelper.RegisterClient(userName, Context.ConnectionId);
            SendPendingMessages();
        }
        return connected;
    }
}
```

This code assumes the following is implemented:

- Client function *sendMessage* to show a private message
- Client function *processPendingMessages* to show all the pending messages
- DataAccess object with methods to Get (*GetPendingMessages*) and Insert (*InsertPendingMessage*) pending messages.
- Helper class *HubHelper* to maintain the current client connections in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction! May I ask what the HubHelper is supposed to mean??

Comment: That's because I'm using In-Memory storage for the connections (I use SignalR v1). http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider. You probably don't need that

Comment: @thepirat000 @devqon Where will be value of  `Context.User.Identity.Name` get assigned?

Comment: @Meetesh That will be the implementation of [asp.net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity)